Syntactic roles of nouns/adjectives
In P. Maas, La critica del testo (trad. G. Ziffer), Edizioni di storia e letteratura, p. 7 we read
Compito della critica del testo è la restituzione di un testo il più vicino possibile all'autografo.
What is the syntactic role of vicino? (Is it an adverbial or does it modify testo?) If it is adverbial, is this form (i.e.adjective?/noun? as adverbial) generalized in italian language? If it is, are there some conditions or any adjective/noun can be an adverb this way inside a sentence?
Furthermore which word exactly does the article determine? (I would say that it determines vicino; though the answer to this question is possible to give another question.)
